# base64_decode() exception when changing URL of Laravel

Tags: php, url, laravel, virtualhost

I have a laravel installation on my server located `/var/www/html/site/` and I can access it here `dev.site.com`. I would like to change the board url to `site.com` simply by changing my document root for that virtual host. So I point `site.com` to `/var/www/html/site/public` and laravel gives back an error:

`base64_decode() expects parameter 1 to be a string, array given`

This only happens when I access the website using the url `site.com` and when I change it back to `dev.site.com`, it's fine again. I've updated the application url to `site.com`.

I'm running laravel 4.2 on centos 4.5 final.

---

### Virtual Hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.site.com
    ServerAlias dev.site.com
    ServerAdmin tech@myDomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site/public"
    <Directory /var/www/html/site/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin tech@myDomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site/public"
    <Directory /var/www/html/site/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

---

/var/www/html/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php

```
 * @param  string  $payload
 * @return array
 *
 * @throws DecryptException
 */
protected function getJsonPayload($payload)
{
    $payload = json_decode(base64_decode($payload), true);
```

---

7 Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter getJsonPayload

```
 * Decrypt the given value.
 *
 * @param  string  $payload
 * @return string
 */
public function decrypt($payload)
{
    $payload = $this->getJsonPayload($payload);

    // We'll go ahead and remove the PKCS7 padding from the encrypted value before
```

### Just to be clear again, if I go to `dev.site.com` it's fine once again.

Comment: What is the string (or array) you're trying to pass look like for the `base64_decode()` function? Please include that code in your question.

Comment: You'll need to include the code that **calls** `getJsonPayload` in order for someone to answer your question.

Comment: I think I got everything in now.

Comment: I've tried searching everywhere for something hard-wired to `dev.site.com` but I couldn't find it. I don't remember ever writing `dev.site.com` anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved simply by clearing my cookies....